# Error running spark-submit - Unable to locate Application.scala file

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to execute spark-submit for my Scala application. I'm receiving an error indicating that the Application.scala file cannot be found, even though it exists within my project. I'd like to understand why this error is occurring and how I can rectify it.

My directory structure and files are as follows:

```
git-scala-streaming
|
| src/streaming/Tools/Tools.scala
| src/streaming/Application.scala
| execute_spark_streaming.sh
| pom.xml
```

Here's the content of the relevant files:

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>debug.spark-example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-</version>
    <inceptionYear>2015</inceptionYear>
    <properties>
        <scala.majorVersion>2.11</scala.majorVersion>
        <scala.minorVersion>.2</scala.minorVersion>
        <spark.version>1.4.1</spark.version>
    </properties>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.majorVersion}${scala.minorVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.majorVersion}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <buildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalabuilder</buildcommand>
                    </buildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalanature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <classpathContainers>
                        <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                        <classpathContainer>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                    </classpathContainers>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attached</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <tarLongFileMode>gnu</tarLongFileMode>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <!-- Include here the dependencies you want to be packed in your fat jar -->
                                    <include>*:*</include>
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Application.scala:

```
package streaming

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Application {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val app = new Application()
    app.run()
  }
}

class Application {

  lazy private val conf = ConfigFactory.load
  lazy private val spark = getSession

  private def run(): Unit = {
    // Your application code can be called here
    val versionInfo = this.versionInfo
    versionInfo.foreach(println)
  }

}
```

execute_spark_streaming.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash


spark-submit --master local[*] --class streaming.Application /home/myprofile/IdeaProjects/git-scala-streaming/target/spark-example-0.1--jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I've tried checking the directory structure, executed mvn clean package to compile the project, and verified that the path to the JAR file in the execute_spark_streaming.sh script is correct. However, I continue to receive the error when running spark-submit.

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to troubleshoot this issue.

Error:

```
Error: Failed to load class streaming.Application.
23/11/26 14:41:05 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
23/11/26 14:41:05 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-f5493a3b-f207-41bf-8b9b-737ab90ca80e
```

Comment: Shouldn't your scala code reside in `src/main/scala` directory instead of just `src/`? To my knowledge that's the maven's defaults and also what you configured in `pom.xml`